# Can't get access to configuration.php Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, admin

Got a site to make some changes. Unfortunately I can't get an access to www/root/configuration.php . Suppose the file was blocked by another user who had admin rights. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear exactly what you mean by 'can't get access' to the configuration file. Maybe it's permission related or maybe the site was customised and the configuration file is in a non-standard location.

Either way there are a couple of options you could try.

I presume you have access to the backend of the site and so you could make most changes from there via Site > Global Configuration.

You can also view almost all the details of the config file from Site > Sytem Information > Configuration File

If neither of these suggestions solved your problem, maybe you could instal a file management component like http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/extplorer and acces the config file that way.

Good luck!